# How to point to a derived class from a base class?

Tags: c++, multithreading

http://s30.postimg.org/oeaimxe40/mendez.jpg

Here is my code. I have a base Thread class and a printerThread-derived class. I call the function. Example:

```
PrinterThread printer;
printer.suspend();
```

I have a thread private value which is null and a non-null printerThread myThread private value. I want to initialize the null value to the printerThread value.

Everything in the picture works properly except the red underline.

Keep in mind I added that entire row AFTER the debug started, otherwise it gives compilation error. How do I access that printThread variable?

Comment: Post code, not images.

Comment: "I added that entire row AFTER the debug started, otherwise it gives compilation error." It gives you error with a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by down casting  your base class

```
PrinterThread *printerThread = dynamic_cast<PrinterThread*>(this);
```

The `printerThread` will be non-null only if the base class is a PrinterThread object. It is probably a better design to a introduce a virtual method and override it in the PrinterThread class.

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense to dynamic_cast<>() in the Thread class, which should have NO CLUE WHATSOEVER about PrinterThread, the virtual method should be redefined in PrinterThread if it is necessary there (i.e. to stop the printing processes on `suspend()`).

Comment: Well, @AlexisWilke, the question was how to do it. I agree with you that it is very difficult to construct a scenario when one should want to access a child class variable directly from the base class.